# Squirrel.Windows Releases file out of sync

Tags: c#, wpf, squirrel.windows

I've been using Squirrel.Windows to deploy a WPF successfully for some time now. I had my machine re-imaged and the `RELEAESES` file inside the `Releases` folder was recreated from scratch since I was excluding this folder entirely in my `.gitignore`. This seems to have broken the auto update functionality for users on a version that was created before I re-imaged.

Is there anything I can set in the `RELEASES` file to force the older versions to pull in the updated ones without recreating all the nuget packages?

Here's the relevant portion of my `RELEASES` file. Users on the version `2.0.6121.16815` are not being automatically migrated to the newer versions at the bottom.

[image: RELEASES File]

Here's my updater code from `app.xaml.cs`. Not sure it's relevant since it's technically running fine.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    using (var mgr = new UpdateManager(updatePath, packageName))
                    {    
                        var updates = await mgr.CheckForUpdate();
                        if (updates.ReleasesToApply.Any())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var lastVersion = updates.ReleasesToApply.OrderBy(x => x.Version).Last();

                                await mgr.DownloadReleases(updates.ReleasesToApply);
                                await mgr.ApplyReleases(updates);

                                try
                                {
                                    latestExe = Path.Combine(mgr.RootAppDirectory, string.Concat("app-", lastVersion.Version), "App.exe");
                                    log.Debug("Latest exe:" + latestExe);
                                    mgr.CreateShortcutsForExecutable(latestExe, DefaultLocations, false);
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex)
                                {
                                    log.Error("error creating shortcuts for executable",ex);

                                }
                                restart = true;
                            }
                            catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                log.Error("Error pulling in updated files", ex);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //No updates
                            log.Debug("No updates available");
                        }
                    }

                    if (restart)
                    {
                        log.Debug("Updated App. Restarting...");
                        UpdateManager.RestartApp(latestExe);

                    }

                }).Wait();
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to reset it so your installs would update to the current version?

Comment: Nope... pretty frustrating. Even posted a question/comment on the Github repo several months back and no response. https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/981